# d3.js - How to do data mapping and filter for Stacked Bar graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am implementing a Stacked Bar graph in d3.js. It is for populations of various categories (category of people) in city over the years . Although I have achieved a bit of outcome with the help of some references but I haven't got the exact result I wanted.

I guess I am facing some problems in data mapping and filter functions, and assigning them in color domain.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my code :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js">
</script>
<script>


var margin = {
  top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40}
    ,
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    yAxMin_PA = 0,
yAxMax_PA = 1500;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var  y = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([yAxMin_PA, yAxMax_PA])
   .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = {
  "bars": [
    {
      "year": 2004,
      "population": [
        {
          "category": 1,
          "strength": 31
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 2,
          "strength": 21
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 3,
          "strength": 41
        }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "year": 2005,
      "population": [
        {
          "category": 1,
          "strength": 23
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 2,
          "strength": 43
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 3,
          "strength": 33
        }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "year": 2006,
      "population": [
        {
          "category": 1,
          "strength": 29
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 2,
          "strength": 41
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 3,
          "strength": 55
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 4,
          "strength": 69
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 5,
          "strength": 89
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 6,
          "strength": 75
        }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "year": 2007,
      "population": [
        {
          "category": 1,
          "strength": 49
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 2,
          "strength": 43
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 3,
          "strength": 25
        }
      ]
    }
    ,
    {
      "year": 2008,
      "population": [
        {
          "category": 1,
          "strength": 20 
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 2,
          "strength": 43
        }
        ,
        {
          "category": 3,
          "strength": 55
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
    ;



x.domain(data.bars.map(function(d) {
  return d.year;
}
                      ));

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.call(yAxis)
.append("text")
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
.attr("y", 6)
.attr("dy", ".71em")
.style("text-anchor", "end")
.text("Population");

for (k = 0; k < data.bars.length; k++) {
var state = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + x(data.bars[k].year) + ",0)";
    });

state.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data.bars[k].population)
    .enter().append("rect")
//.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
.attr("class", "rect_grp" + k)
    .attr("id", function (d, i) {
        return "rect" + i;
    })
    .attr("width", function () {
        return x.rangeBand();
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) { /*console.log("hiii");*/
        if (i != 0) {

            var prevHgt = d3.select(".rect_grp" + k + "#rect" + (i - 1)).attr("height"); // Select height of previous rectangle
            var ylimit = d3.select(".rect_grp" + k + "#rect" + (i - 1)).attr("y"); // Select y of previous rectangle
            console.log("prevHgt=>" + prevHgt);

            return ((parseFloat(ylimit)) - (parseFloat(prevHgt)));
        } else {
            return y(d.strength);
        }
    })
    .attr("height", function (d, i) {

        return (Math.round(y(yAxMin_PA)) - Math.round(y(d.strength)));

    })
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {
        console.log(i);
        return color(i);
    });
```

}

```
</script>
```

Comment: So what's your question? What do you want to achieve and where does your current solution fall short?

Comment: Well I am not getting the categories in the color domain. For eg- I need all the categories in the color domain for every year (such as for year 2004 we have three categories of people "category": 1,"category": 2,"category": 3). 

If you run this code you will see the problem.

Comment: You may find it easier to start with [NVD3](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html).

Comment: I took the reference of https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/d3-js/G47LtWNXPqg/t6grOHdKqt4J .

Anyway there has to be someway of doing it with d3.js.

Comment: Well yes, I'm saying that for the purpose of learning how to do it, NVD3 may be something you might find useful. There are plenty of examples of stacked bar charts with D3 (e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)) that you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it is useful to give people the example instead of making them run it themselves. See here: http://tributary.io/inlet/5835233.

Around line 157 where it says

```
d.population.forEach (function(d){
  color.domain(d3.keys(d).filter(function(name) {
  return name;
}
```

`name` is always either `"category"` or `"strength"`. This is because of how your data is arranged. I think what you want is to have your data be

```
{year: 2008, 
population: {
    category1: 20,
    category2: 43,
    category3: 55}
}
```

If you put your data like this, you'll have to mess around with how exactly you are setting the domain of your `color` instance, since `forEach` only works on arrays, and we have now set the data to be in an object. Something like `color.domain(d3.keys(d.population))`. Fork my example on tributary and try a couple things. Look at the `d3.keys()` documentation to see how it works.

Comment: thanks .. your answer was helpful . Please help me out in the edited code. I am getting the value of every attribute of rectangle except "height". Why is it so ??

Comment: Ok.. I got it, was just missing a DOM concept.